# Redeem code option method not showing in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, promotion-code

I have developed an app in unreal engine with one in-app purchase item, I created some promo codes, they are working fine in my region, but a customer in Ecuador told me that the option to redeem the code in the app is not showing as a payment option, any idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.